# How to exclude web-jars from processing with sbt-closure?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-web

I am using sbt-web pipeline with sbt-closure, but by default it processes all assests including web-jars with causes problems with Reactjs files.

How to exclude web-jars from processing with sbt-closure and process only my own javascript files?

Answer (score 0):

You can user include / exclude filter

```
includeFilter in closure := GlobFilter("*/react/*.js")

excludeFilter in closure := (excludeFilter in closure).value ||  GlobFilter("*/react/*.js")
```

You'll find more exemple in sbt-closure source code https://github.com/noisycr1cket/sbt-closure/blob/master/src/main/scala/net/ground5hark/sbt/closure/SbtClosure.scala or in the sbt doc https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Include%2Fexclude+files+in+the+source+directory